# What triggers GC other than memory allocations?

Tags: go

let's say I write zero allocation Go program,
Can I safely assume that GC is never called at all?

by the way, I'm aware of `GOGC=off`, I want to know what causes GC other than allocating memory itself

Comment: Any answer will depend on a specific Go compiler (or, more precisely, runtime). A garbage collector isn't even prescribed by the language spec. I suspect the [mark phase of the standard Go implementation](https://go.dev/doc/gc-guide) will always happen (with GOGC=on). Try `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` to find out.

Comment: With the standard go implementation, you also need to remember that CG is concurrent with multiple phases, so it's not clear what being "called" actually means. Like Peter mentioned, using he `gctrace` output is a good way to see what's going on.

Comment: I also wonder if some parts of the Go runtime (which is present and active in any running Go program) do allocation when the runtime is "routinely powering" even an otherwise zero-allocating program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot safely assume that the Go garbage collector is never called, even in a zero-allocation Go program. The Go GC can be triggered by various runtime operations such as goroutine creation, map/slice operations, channel operations, and more, even if you don't explicitly allocate memory.